# How to sort pandas dataframe in a special way

Tags: python, pandas

Given a pandas dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
                   'b': [0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3]})
```

How to sort it along the column `b` in such a way that it is rearranged as `{0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3}`.

I.e. the resulting dataframe is

```
1   0
3   1
5   2
7   3
2   0
4   1
6   2
8   3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution, with quick benchmark:

```
pd.DataFrame(sorted(df.values.tolist(), key=lambda k: (k[0]%2==0, k[1])), columns=['a', 'b'])
```

Prints:

```
   a  b
0  1  0
1  3  1
2  5  2
3  7  3
4  2  0
5  4  1
6  6  2
7  8  3
```

Benchmark:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
                   'b': [0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3]})


from timeit import timeit

def f1():
    return pd.DataFrame(sorted(df.values.tolist(), key=lambda k: (k[0]%2==0, k[1])), columns=['a', 'b'])

def f2():
    s = df.groupby('b').cumcount().sort_values(kind='mergesort')
    return df.loc[s.index]

def f3():
    return df.iloc[np.lexsort([df['b'], df.groupby('b').cumcount()])]

t1 = timeit(lambda: f1(), number=1_000)
t2 = timeit(lambda: f2(), number=1_000)
t3 = timeit(lambda: f3(), number=1_000)

print(t1)
print(t2)
print(t3)
```

Prints (AMD 2400G/Ubuntu 18.04, Python 3.8.3, Pandas 1.0.3):

```
0.45131446300365496
2.2533202580088982
1.6977271080104401
```

So solution with `sorted()` seems fastest.

EDIT: After around ~3000 elements the solution with `np.lexsort` starts to win.

Comment: time benchmarks don't make sense on small data.  You want to show how it scales with larger data so that we get a sense of the order of it's efficiency.

Comment: @piRSquared Yes, around ~3000 elements there's break-even. Then the solution with `np.lexsort` starts to win. I put that in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

#### Add a column using `cumcount`

```
df.assign(x=df.groupby('b').cumcount()).sort_values(['x', 'b']).drop('x', axis=1)

   a  b
0  1  0
2  3  1
4  5  2
6  7  3
1  2  0
3  4  1
5  6  2
7  8  3
```

---

#### Numpy's `lexsort`, `iloc`, and `cumcount`

```
df.iloc[np.lexsort([df['b'], df.groupby('b').cumcount()])]

   a  b
0  1  0
2  3  1
4  5  2
6  7  3
1  2  0
3  4  1
5  6  2
7  8  3
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's try:

```
s = df.groupby('b').cumcount().sort_values(kind='mergesort')

df = df.loc[s.index]
```

Output:

```
   a  b
0  1  0
2  3  1
4  5  2
6  7  3
1  2  0
3  4  1
5  6  2
7  8  3
```

Comment: That is quite brilliant.  This breaks if the index isn't unique.  You can use `argsort` instead with `iloc`: `df.iloc[df.groupby('b').cumcount().argsort(kind='mergesort')]`

Answer (score 0):

This is simplistic and specific to your question, and builds off of the knowledge that column b is already sorted :

```
res = df.to_numpy()

pd.DataFrame(np.vstack((res[::2],res[1::2])),columns=df.columns)

#similar
pd.concat((df.iloc[::2], df.iloc[1::2]))


    a   b
0   1   0
1   3   1
2   5   2
3   7   3
4   2   0
5   4   1
6   6   2
7   8   3
```